# Displaying a list of items in a neat and readable way

Tags: usability, readability, content

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [When displaying statistics to a user, is it better to bold the data or the label?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/7938/when-displaying-statistics-to-a-user-is-it-better-to-bold-the-data-or-the-label)

I often have to display 2 column lists like this -

Name:    Bob

Age: 30

Shoes: Trainers

etc.

I normally align these lists so they look a bit neater but I was wondering should I make one of the columns a different font weight / style so the user could distinguish between them, like this -

**Name:**    Bob

**Age:** 30

**Shoes:** Trainers

*or*

Name:    **Bob**

Age: **30**

Shoes: **Trainers**

---

**How should I be presenting these lists?**

Comment: Didn't see that one. Yes that answers my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither one. You right-align the left column and left-align the right column making it easier for the user to scan the text since there is only one line (not drawn, but clearly shown in if you connect the colons) to follow. The same goes for any Label with text input field to the right. Like this:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhsub2.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>